# Existing object is not found in complete function

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a data frame with the following columns `Entity`, `Customer Class`, `Month` and other

```
|CClass |Entity  |Month| Sales volume|
|-------|--------|-----|-------------|
|Bakery | 1      | 1   |100          |
|Bakery | 1      | 2   |106          |
|Bakery | 1      | 3   |103          |
|Bakery | 1      | 5   |135          |
|Bakery | 1      | 6   |121          |
|Bakery | 1      | 7   |176          |
|Bakery | 1      | 10  |133          |
|Bakery | 1      | 11  |100          |
|Bakery | 1      | 12  |112          |
|Bakery | 2      | 1   |136          |
|Bakery | 2      | 3   |123          |
|Bakery | 2      | 4   |108          |
|Bakery | 2      | 5   |101          |
|Bakery | 2      | 7   |105          |
|Bakery | 3      | 10  |103          |
|Bakery | 3      | 11  |106          |
|Bakery | 3      | 12  |110          |
|Grocery| 1      | 1   |120          |
|Grocery| 1      | 2   |150          |
```

When I try to populate the missing `Month` to each `Customer Class` using the complete() function:

DF <- complete(DF, nesting(`Entity`, `CClass`), `Month`)

I got the Error message "! object 'Entity' not found"

> st <- complete(ST, nesting(Entity, CClass), SBMONTH)
> Error in `dplyr::summarise()`:
> ! Problem while computing `..1 = complete(data = dplyr::cur_data(), ..., fill = fill, explicit = explicit)`.
> i The error occurred in group 1: CClass = "Bagel Shop", End Market = "Food Service", Entity = 1.
> Caused by error:
> ! object 'Entity' not found
> Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

But with the testing samples this function works.
Please advise

Comment: Please post a reproducible example of a few rows of your data. `dput()` is nice for creating reproducible examples that are copy/pasteable and include all class and structure information, so `dput(DF[1:5, c("Entity", "Customer Class", "Month")])` will give us the first 5 rows of those 3 columns.

Comment: The code you show is a bit confusing because if you actually have a space in your column name, you should be using backticks to quote the column... seems like it would just be a syntax error the way you have it now.

Comment: Even if I renamed the variable "Customer Class" into CClass the situation is the same. But when I try to run the sample code from another source like manual it works

Comment: I didn't think that was your problem, just something confusing about the question. How about that reproducible example??

Comment: | Customer Class | End Market | Entity | SBMONTH | Seasonality |
|------------------|--------------|--------|-------------|--------------|
|Bagel Shop        |Food Service|  1        |    1             |   0.0567      |
|Bagel Shop        |Food Service|  1        |    2             |   0.0567      |  To reproduce the "Customer Class" - "Entity" to every month I use the following df <- complete(df, nesting(Entity, 'Customer Class'), SBMONTH)

Comment: Please put it in your question, not in comments. And please please use `dput()` so it is copy/pasteable, already in valid R syntax, and includes the column classes. And while a small example is nice, it does need to reproduce the problem--a single row will not work well with `complete`. 3 to 5 rows would be best.

Comment: Greetings! As others have said, usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Comment: Also, please don't spam tags. The `complete` function is from `tidyr`, not `dplyr`. And unless you've tried the code in the R Gui or R command line and also RStudio, and the problem only occurs in RStudio, the problem has nothing to do with RStudio, the app that is most common for writing R code.

Comment: This may be caused by the data being grouped by CClass. Please make sure to `ungroup()` the data before using `complete()`.

Answer (score 1):

are you sure that your `DF` object class is `data.frame` or `data.table`? Because I got the same error on a `tbl` object and it returned me the same error (tbh I used the function `expand`, but I think it's the same matter). Moreover, I tried to replicate your error using your code by first creating a `data.frame`:

> DF <- data.frame(     CClass=c(rep("Bakery",17), rep("Grocery", 2)),
> Entity=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,1,1),
> Month=c(1,2,3,5,6,7,10,11,12,1,3,4,5,7,10,11,12,1,2),   `Sales volume`=c(100,106,103,135,121,176,133,100,112,136,123,108,101,105,103,106,110,120,150)
> )

and then by running your command (`DF <- complete(DF, nesting(Entity, CClass), Month)`). Here's the output

`DF`

> A tibble: 40 × 4    Entity CClass Month Sales.volume
>              1      1 Bakery     1          100  2      1 Bakery     2          106  3      1 Bakery     3
> 103  4      1 Bakery     4           NA  5      1 Bakery     5
> 135  6      1 Bakery     6          121  7      1 Bakery     7
> 176  8      1 Bakery    10          133  9      1 Bakery    11
> 100 10      1 Bakery    12          112
> … with 30 more rows
> ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows

Hope this was useful.
Giuseppe

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the error. Starting from a fresh R session and using this data:

```
DF = read.table(text = 'CClass Entity  Month Sales_volume
Bakery  1       1   100          
Bakery  1       2   106          
Bakery  1       3   103          
Bakery  1       5   135          
Bakery  1       6   121          
Bakery  1       7   176          
Bakery  1       10  133          
Bakery  1       11  100          
Bakery  1       12  112          
Bakery  2       1   136          
Bakery  2       3   123          
Bakery  2       4   108          
Bakery  2       5   101          
Bakery  2       7   105          
Bakery  3       10  103          
Bakery  3       11  106          
Bakery  3       12  110          
Grocery 1       1   120          
Grocery 1       2   150', header = T)
```

I load `tidyr` and run the `complete` command you have in your question and get reasonable-looking output:

```
library(tidyr)
complete(DF, nesting(Entity, CClass), Month)
# # A tibble: 40 × 4
#    Entity CClass Month Sales_volume
#     <int> <chr>  <int>        <int>
#  1      1 Bakery     1          100
#  2      1 Bakery     2          106
#  3      1 Bakery     3          103
#  4      1 Bakery     4           NA
#  5      1 Bakery     5          135
#  6      1 Bakery     6          121
#  7      1 Bakery     7          176
#  8      1 Bakery    10          133
#  9      1 Bakery    11          100
# 10      1 Bakery    12          112
# # … with 30 more rows
# # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Some ideas: make sure you are using `tidyr::complete`, if you loaded another package with a `complete` function that might be masking the correct version. You can check `conflicts()` and see if `complete` is listed, and if so specify `tidyr::complete` to get the correct version. Also check `names(DF)` and make sure your column names are exactly what you think they are--no extra whitespace, capitalized correctly, etc. Also check the `class(DF)` and make sure it is `data.frame` or `tbl_df`, and maybe have a look at `str(DF)` to make sure the columns are appropriate classes. Since you didn't use `dput()` to share your data, we can't be sure what the class of the data or the columns are.

If you still have trouble, please try to find a sample of data that reproduces the problem and **please use `dput` to share it**.